# Problem in retrieving data from google firestore which contains multiple collections and documents

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to Firestore.I've used set function to store data into firestore.
My Database is like the following

```
Park -->Krishna -->802 -->2020 -->1 -->5 --> block:"Krishna"
                                               date:"5/01/2020"
                                               units:"100"

Park -->Godavari -->101 -->2020 -->1 -->8 --> block:"Godavari"
                                                date:"8/01/2020"
                                                units:"200"
```

I need to access units and display them using Toast.

My XML code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical"
>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/get"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="Fetch data" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textDisplay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

And my java code is:

```
Button fetch;TextView td;


fetch = (Button)findViewById(R.id.get);
td=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textDisplay);

DocumentReference user = db.collection("park").document("Godavari").collection("101").document("2020").collection("1").document("8");
efetch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Clicked on fetch",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    user.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
      if(documentSnapshot != null && documentSnapshot.exists())
      {
          Log.i("Data is",documentSnapshot.getData("units").toString());
          td.setText(documentSnapshot.getData("units").toString());
      }
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Unable to fetch data",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
} });
```

When I click on Fetch button I must get units(in this case it is 200) and display it in my textview.

But when I click Fetch button, It is showing that "documentSnapshot" is null.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: How do you know that `documentSnapshot` is null here?  Your code is checking for two conditions, both null and exists.

Comment: I've placed Log.i("Data is",documentSnapshot.getData().toString());
              td.setText(documentSnapshot.getData().toString()); this in if(documentSnapshot != null && documentSnapshot.exists()). And it is displaying null.

Comment: That's not the same as documentSnapshot being null.  What you're seeing is the data in the snapshot is null, because the document you're requesting doesn't exist.  Make sure you're requesting the correct document.

Comment: I've checked that. I'm calling the correct path of collections and documents. There is no way to share a screenshot of those collections and databases.How can I show you my database.

Comment: Please add your database structure as a screenshot using [imgbb.com](https://imgbb.com/). Please also respond with @AlexMamo